# Can I sync podcasts only with iPhone5?

Tags: ios, iphone, podcasts

I just subscribed to a bunch of podcasts for the first time. 
Never had podcasts on my phone or iTunes before today. 
I would like to sync them directly to my phone without saving them permanently on my computer. 
Is this possible ootb? 
Is there a free app that would make it easier?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need to use a third party app in order to not have them sync with iTunes. I've bought three different podcast apps and I finally found one that I like and I can live with the bugs.  None of these apps are very expensive, but Instacast keeps putting out new paid versions, instead of updating the old one.

In order of My preference:

1. [iCatcher](http://appshopper.com/news/icatcher-a-podcast-catcher-app) $3. The interface is a bit cluttered, but it works and syncs with other iOS devices via iCloud flawlessly. Has an option to resume playing when the headphones are plugged in.
2. [Downcast](http://appshopper.com/news/downcast) $2. Has many of the same options as iCatcher, but it is pretty buggy and  crashes on older devices (iPod Touch 3rd generation) after playing for 20-30 minutes. Also has issues with the integration in my car.
3. [Instacast](http://appshopper.com/news/instacast-the-next-gen-podcast-app) $5. I didn't like the organization or the interface. The playlist & sorting options are very limited.

I have deleted Downcast and Instacast from all of my devices since iCatcher works so well for me.